# How does the molecule consisting of two bridged aromatic rings look in 3D?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, molecular-structure

I can't understand how the following compound with bridged benzene rings looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [cyclophane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclophane), namely **4,8-dibromo[2.2]paracyclophane**.
Lonsdale et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1960.0055)] first structurally characterized [2.2]paracyclophane in 1960:

> The molecule consists of two facing benzene rings linked in para-positions by two $\ce{(CH2)2}$ bridges.
> As a result of steric hindrance, the benzene rings are each bent into a boat-shape, but even so, their maximum distance apart in the molecule is only 3.09 Å, whereas the normal van der Waals distance is upwards of 3.4 Å.
>
> […]
>
> The angle of bending of the benzene ring (14°) does not change
> with temperature, but the aliphatic $\ce{CH2-CH2}$ bond appears to be unusually long at room temperatures* and has decreased by 0.07 Å at 93 °K. Moreover, although the distance between the two benzene rings does not change, there is a decrease of 0.03 Å in the overall length of the molecule from 291 to 93 °K.
>
> […]
>
> [image: Structure of [2.2]paracyclophane]
> **Figure 4.** Diagram showing projection of molecules at $0, 0, 0;$ $1/2, 1/2, 1/2$ and $0, 0, 1$ on to $(100).$

---

* The $\ce{CH2-CH2}$ bond length is 1.63 Å, which is above average 1.54 Å expected for the aliphatic $\ce{C-C}$ bond.

See [CCDC entry DXYLEN](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Doi=10.1098%2Frspa.1960.0055&DatabaseToSearch=Published) for more details and an interactive 3D image.

Several related polysubstituted [2.2]paracyclophanes have been reported:

- 5,7-dibromo-4-hydroxy[2.2]paracyclophane [[2](https://doi.org/10.1002/ejoc.201403316)] ([CCDC: FULNUX](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Doi=10.1002%2Fejoc.201403316&DatabaseToSearch=Published));
- 4,8,12,16-tetrabromo[2.2]paracyclophane [[3](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2005-872270)] ([CCDC: SAWDIE](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Doi=10.1055%2Fs-2005-872270&DatabaseToSearch=Published));
- 4,5,7,8,12,13,15,16-octabromo[2.2]paracyclophane [[3](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2005-872270)] ([CCDC: SAWDEA](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Doi=10.1055%2Fs-2005-872270&DatabaseToSearch=Published)).

#### References

1. Lonsdale, K. Y.; Milledge, H. J.; Rao, K. K. V. Studies of the structure, thermal expansion and molecular vibrations of di-p-xylylene, $\ce{C16H16},$ at 93 and 291 °K. *Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A* **1960**, 255 (1280), 82–100. DOI: [10.1098/rspa.1960.0055](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1960.0055).
2. Atman Vorontsova, N. V.; Zhuravsky, R. P.; Antonov, D. Yu.; Sergeeva, E. V.; Godovikov, I. A.; Starikova, Z. A.; Vologzhanina, A. V. Synthesis of Bromo-Substituted 4-Hydroxy[2.2]Paracyclophanes and [2.2]Paracyclophane-4,7-Quinones as Versatile Chiral Building Blocks: [2.2]Paracyclophane Derivatives as Versatile Chiral Building Blocks. *Eur. J. Org. Chem.* **2015**(2), 325–330. DOI: [10.1002/ejoc.201403316](https://doi.org/10.1002/ejoc.201403316).
3. Chow, H.-F.; Low, K.-H.; Wong, K. Y. An Improved Method for the Regiospecific Synthesis of Polysubstituted [2.2]Paracyclophanes. *Synlett* **2005**, No. 14, 2130–2134. DOI: [10.1055/s-2005-872270](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2005-872270).